# Code assistent for javascript in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, aptana, content-assist

Version - Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.2.201208201020

Project was created by File -> New -> PHP Project.

This is the content of index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function addOption() {
        var option = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("answersList").appendChild(option);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="addOption();">Add option</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are no createElement and getElementById methids in completion list for document.

How can I get code completion?

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems that code completion works well for pure JavaScript files (*.js).

Comment: I think it should be a Web / JavaScript project in order to get code completion for JS.

Comment: As I read [here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/1172-web-vs-php-project-vs-web-project#comment_7831238) PHP project is appropriate.